# AngularJS in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am trying to build a web app following [Spring and Angular JS](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/spring-and-angular-js-a-secure-single-page-application#add-a-home-page). I am not able to run the app for the following error:

> Failed to execute goal ro.isdc.wro4j:wro4j-maven-plugin:1.6.3:run (default) on project demo: Exception occured while processing: Exception while loading properties file from /home/san2/SpringAngularJS/demo1/src/main/wro/wro.properties: /home/san2/SpringAngularJS/demo1/src/main/wro/wro.properties (No such file or directory)

which is pointing to [MojoExecutionException](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException)

here is my pom.xml

```
<groupId>org.test</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-session-ui</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Spring Session UI</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <wro4j.version>1.7.6</wro4j.version>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Serves *only* to filter the wro.xml so it can get an absolute 
                        path for the project -->
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/wro</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/wro</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${wro4j.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <wroManagerFactory>ro.isdc.wro.maven.plugin.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory</wroManagerFactory>
                <cssDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/static/css</cssDestinationFolder>
                <jsDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/static/js</jsDestinationFolder>
                <wroFile>${project.build.directory}/wro/wro.xml</wroFile>
                <extraConfigFile>${basedir}/src/main/wro/wro.properties</extraConfigFile>
                <contextFolder>${basedir}/src/main/wro</contextFolder>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                    <artifactId>angularjs</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.8</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone-local</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: This problem has nothing to with AngularJs

Comment: Have you actually read the stack trace/error? It clearly states what is missing.

Comment: Where is wro.properties file located in your project ?

Comment: it worked. Thanks to all